# Open Office: Tool for managing bibliography?

Tags: openoffice.org, bibliography

OO native tool seems not very comfortable. 
I think it's better to store data in XML or biblatex format.
What do you use and which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

Try [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/).